# Accessing Pipeline variables inside the Python script

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a scenario where I need to run Python script from the Azure Repos with Pipeline and I have API auth key that I need to store in Azure Pipeline variables. The key is stored, but the question is how to use it in Python script and when it's executing it pulls the variable from the Azure Variables. I have tried to search for example, but not really much about Python except bash and PowerShell on Microsoft Docs.

How do I add it here? This is not an inline script, but the one that's in Azure Repos. I am running this script from the Azure Pipeline.

[screenshot of the python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfNWu.png)

**Any example is much appreciated!**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [variable value at runtime with macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) - for example `$(ApiAuthKey)` - and pass it via the [`arguments` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#run-python-scripts), so in your pipeline:

```yaml
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: filePath
    scriptPath: path/to/script.py
    arguments: $(ApiAuthKey)
```

In python you [access the arguments with the list `sys.argv`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv):

```py
auth_ticket = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this. This did solve my problem. :))